# Can't use printf or debugger in Intel SDK for OpenCL

Tags: visual-studio, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, intel

I'm using the Intel SDK for OpenCL with an Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU to successfully run an OpenCL program.  I've made sure to link against the Intel OpenCL libraries since I also have Nvidia libraries installed.

However, putting a `printf()` call in the kernel gives the OpenCL compiler error

> error: implicit declaration of function 'printf' is not allowed in OpenCL

Also, I've enabled OpenCL kernel debugging in the Visual Studio 2012 plugin, and passed the following options to clBuildProgram:

```
"-g -s C:\\Path\\to\\my\\program.cl"
```

However, kernel breakpoints are skipped.  Hovering over the breakpoint gives the message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

My kernels are in a separate .cl file, and I'm setting the breakpoints the way I would for C/C++ code.  Is this the correct way to set breakpoints using the Intel SDK for OpenCL debugger?

**Why are `printf()` calls and breakpoints not working with the Intel SDK for OpenCL?**

Comment: Did you enable printf by adding `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_intel_printf : enable` somewhere before the statement?

Comment: @MatthiasHolzapfel Yes, I tried that.

Comment: Hi,
I am having the same issue what you faced earlier.
I am not able to Debug my Kernel and the Breakpoints are not being hit.
I am using Intel OpenCL SDK 2014 with Visual Studio 2010.
If you have found the Solution, would grateful if you can share the Solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe function printf() was introduced in the OCL version 1.2. Intel released this version not that long time ago. I'd bet that you still have the 1.1 version.

Regarding the debugger I almost never used it but based on this [document](http://driveragent.com/c/archive/1c33f9b5/image/135-4-310/Intel-Onboard-Graphics-Driver,-Lenovo-H520s) the path is supposed to be given like that:

```
"-g -s \"C:\\Path\\to\\my\\program.cl\""
```

You are also supposed to choose which thread you wanna debug.

Comment: Thanks for the  link and the fix, but the problem persists.  I just downloaded the Intel version yesterday.

Comment: I have the same issue, running VS2017, path is correct, breakpoint is not hit, using Intel compiler. Did you solve the issue in the meantime?